# WaIISHost flatlining web-role

Tags: performance, iis, deployment, azure, azure-web-roles

First off, I'm very new to Azure.

I've successfully deployed an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application to Azure, using a web role. The app uses Entity Framework and SQL Azure.

Recently I've done some changes (some including adding appsettings), and tried to upgrade the application. When upgrading, it took quite a long time, before Aborting. I've always deployed through the management portal Silverlight application at http://windows.azure.com.

When trying again to no avail, I setup remote desktop and deployed again. The remote desktop session was extremely slow, and it turned out to be because WaIISHost was putting the CPU to 100%.

The IIS Manager shows that the application is deployed and 'started', however I cannot navigate to the site in the VM, and the deployment constantly seems to be trying to update without success and eventually aborting and retrying, (as I write this, it's currently Busy and Waiting for role to start...).

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem could be?

I believe all the right dependencies are set to copy local, which is [a possible problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512228/microsoft-azure-mvc-3-web-role-not-starting-after-adding-twiliocontroller-base). It is extremely hard to debug this issue, as the remote desktop session hangs so often due to the 100% CPU utilization, and the recycling/restarting/reupdating of the web role from time to time.

Thanks,

James

P.S. Hope some of that made at least some sense...

Comment: I believe WaIISHost is basically the "startup" process. If it's maxed out, that suggests to me that something may be going sideways in your OnStart() method, or the Run() method if you have one. Have you changed anything there?

Comment: @breischl No, the web role wasn't doing anything in the OnStart method. Turned out this was due to Microsoft.ReportViewer.* DLL's not being set to copy local, and hence not in the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that there's something doing in your WebRole.OnStart and/or Run, which caused the WaIISHost uses 100% CPU. Can you remove all codes from the WebRole.OnStart and/or Run and try again.

And it might be helpful to turn on the IntelliTrace when deploying, so that you can download the trace and find out any exceptions occurred when your application started, even before the website started.

Comment: Turns out it was the Microsoft.ReportViewer.* DLL's that weren't set to copy local. I'll mark your suggestion as the answer, as IntelliTrace did actually help to resolve this.